# currentplacewithcallback not being called in google place iOS api

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api

I am trying to get current place based on google place API iOS, other API for place picker, add place is calling callback methods, but when i am trying to get current place with below code, it not giving any error or not even calling callback method.

```
_placesClient = [GMSPlacesClient sharedClient];


[_placesClient currentPlaceWithCallback:^(GMSPlaceLikelihoodList *likelihoodList, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Current Place error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }
    int cnt =0;
    for (GMSPlaceLikelihood *likelihood in likelihoodList.likelihoods) {
        cnt++;
        if(cnt==1)
        {

            GMSPlace* place = likelihood.place;
            NSLog(@"Current Place name %@ at likelihood %g", place.name, likelihood.likelihood);
            NSLog(@"Current Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
            NSLog(@"Current Place attributions %@", place.attributions);
            NSLog(@"Current PlaceID %@", place.placeID);

            CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(place.coordinate.latitude,place.coordinate.longitude);
            //                CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lat doubleValue],[lng doubleValue]);

            CLLocationCoordinate2D northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude + 0.001, center.longitude + 0.001);
            CLLocationCoordinate2D southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - 0.001, center.longitude - 0.001);
            GMSCoordinateBounds *viewport = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:northEast
                                                                                 coordinate:southWest];
            GMSPlacePickerConfig *config = [[GMSPlacePickerConfig alloc] initWithViewport:viewport];
            _placePicker = [[GMSPlacePicker alloc] initWithConfig:config];

            [_placePicker pickPlaceWithCallback:^(GMSPlace *place, NSError *error) {
                if (error != nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Pick Place error %@", [error localizedDescription]);

                }
                if (place != nil) {
                    [_placesClient reportDeviceAtPlaceWithID:place.placeID];

                    NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);
                    NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
                    NSLog(@"Place placeID %@", place.placeID);
                    NSLog(@"Place number %@", place.phoneNumber);
                    NSLog(@"Place website %@", place.website);

                    self.placeInfo = [[SHPlaceInfo alloc]init];
                    self.placeInfo.address=place.formattedAddress;
                    self.placeInfo.phnNumber=place.phoneNumber;
                    self.placeInfo.website = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",place.website];
                    self.placeInfo.idStr = place.placeID;
                    self.placeInfo.lat =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", place.coordinate.latitude];
                    self.placeInfo.lng =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", place.coordinate.longitude];
                    self.placeInfo.type = [place.types componentsJoinedByString:@","];
                    self.placeInfo.name = place.name;
                    [self savePlaceDatainDatabase:self.placeInfo];

                    //            [self getNearDetailPlaces];

                    //if place id gives phone number then need to use below flow and remove api call above getNearDetailPlaces

                    selectedPlaceDetailViewController *placeDetailVC=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"selectedPlaceDetailViewController"];

                    placeDetailVC.placeInfo = self.placeInfo;
                    placeDetailVC.strCalledFromPage=@"Home";
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController: placeDetailVC animated:YES];


                } else {
                    NSLog(@"No place selected");
                }
            }];
        }

    }

}];
```

Comment: How long did you wait for the callback to be called? This would take a while.

Comment: i have waited for even 5 minutes but still its not being called.

Comment: Have the permissions for location been asked for? Also, which device are you using to test the application?

Comment: yes it is asking for permission whenever i am installing app in device  and i am using iPad2 for testing

Comment: On iOS, you need to ask for permissions when the app is running (not at install time).

Can you add the code you are using to ask for the location permission to your code above so we can verify it is correct?

Comment: Also to confirm: Are other Places API methods working correctly, and are you initializing the client with an API key in your appdelegate?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility: you might not be retaining a reference to `_placesClient`.

The outstanding callback alone won't keep the `GMSPlacesClient` instance alive, so if you don't ensure your program keeps a reference to it the callback might never be fired, which matches the symptom you see.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure with exact issue, but after running this in iPhone6 its calling that callback method,it can be issue of OS version also.Google Place API for iOS is only supported in latest version of OS.and i have got this spark from @ZeMoon's answer.

Thank you all for reply

Comment: The Google Places API for iOS works with iOS 7.0 and up. What were you using to test it beforehand?

Comment: yes you are correct i was using older version so it was creating issue 
Thanks plexer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and just like you it seems to work only on iPhone 6 simulator and up, so it is probably due to the assumed iOS version on the simulated devices.